# if "0" in self.br.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='counter']").text: (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

my code:

```
if "0" in self.br.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='counter']").text:
```

is trying find out if it's 0 in the following html part

```
<span style="color: green;" id="counter">1</span>
```

my code doesn't seems to work... Not sure why is this because it's digits and not letters? I have such function on other part of the page and it works fine.

Comment: Could you note what is printed: `print self.br.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='counter']").text` and `type(self.br.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='counter']").text)`?

Comment: @alecxe sure just a moment

Comment: @alecxe returned type unicode only.

Comment: @MarkVoidale and `print self.br.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='counter']").text`?

Comment: @arminrigo it didn't print anything

Comment: update: `self.br.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='counter']").get_attribute("innerHTML"):` will print the right number but the `if "0" in self.br.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='counter']").get_attribute("innerHTML"):` doesn't work! >.<

Comment: @MarkVoidale If you have extra information, it's best to edit your question to include it there. It's a lot more readable than putting it in comments, and it also means that any new readers can get all the information they need by reading just the question; they don't have to also scan through all the comments and responses.